# Using Eclipse, is there an "All" macro/function

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

First, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE - this is not a religious discussion about editors.  I just want a How To sort of answer.

That said, in editors where the data is seen as a matrix (sometimes called Eastern Orthodox Editors, examples: SlickEdit, Xedit, E/PM and the switch+alt+A block mode in eclipse) rather than a long string broken into rows (Western Orthodox Editors)  it is possible to have a function, usually called "ALL" that takes a search argument and shows only ALL the lines containing that search.  So if you had a file like:

```
11 22 33 44 55
22 33 44 55 66
33 44 55 66 77
77 88 99 00 11
```

and issued an ALL for "11", you'd see only the lines with 11 in them:

```
11 22 33 44 55
77 88 99 00 11
```

The other lines would be hidden and, most importantly, any edits applied would only act on the visible lines, not on the hidden one(s).

So, it there a tool, add-on, built-in, whatever, that will do this for Eclipse?  And for that matter MS/VS and NetBeans?

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you looked? What keywords have you already searched? Have you looked into writing the plugin yourself? You know stackoverflow isn't a google replacement right?

Comment: No, it is a search tool using the great collective base of knowledge that is StackOverflow, not the brain dead word matching done by google.  I ask here when I know, intuitively or from sampling, that you can't ask certain questions on google and ever expect to find an answer.  I overlook the occasional pedantic remark.

Comment: To whomever it was, what are the down votes for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of such an editor function, but you can do a file search specifying the string and the search view will give you a list of the lines containing the string.  It's just that the list is displayed as a tree and not a solid block of text.